# Embedding a webkit-based webview in a Windows Store app

Tags: webview, webkit, windows-store-apps

I want to embed a webkit-based webview in my Windows Store app. I tried using CefSharp and Awesomium, but unfortunately they are using APIs that store apps can't use (e.g. System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost).

Are there any webkit-based libraries that are known to work in a Windows Store app?

Update: I tried calling into CEF directly without a wrapper, but the CEF dll failed to load, presumably because it calls APIs that are not available for Windows Store apps